# getting only #text and null when trying to get value from xml

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to use an xml file to be able to access locations of user specified files however with the one I have created I keep getting a #text for one method and the other gives [Settings: null]

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import utils.Cryption;
import utils.CryptoException;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws CryptoException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {        
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = builder.parse(new File("D:\\Projects\\Utils\\exampleSettings.xml"));
    NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Settings");
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.toString());
    }
    Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    String hold = getSeting("debugLocation", rootElement);
    System.out.println(hold);
}

private static String getSeting(String tagName, Element element) {
    NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
        NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();
        if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
            return subList.item(0).getNodeName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

This is the xml file

```
<Settings>

<debugLocation> test </debugLocation>

</Settings>
```

I thought I should be getting test back but its not.

Comment: Can u follow this link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Have you tried return `subList.item(0).getTextContent()`?

Comment: @LearningPhase That link worked. Thank you for your help.